# How to sum in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

Im new to Crystal report. Would appreciate for your help and advice. 
I have applied the 1st formula add into the crystal report and trying to sum it if the value is only 1. Attempted to create 2nd formula but having the error.

1. Formula: test3
   if(Count ({CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEID}, {CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEID})) = 2 then 1 else 0
2. sum ({@Test3}) 
   error - this field cannot be summarized

Answer (score 0):

Crystal cannot total formulas that depend on totals.

You can define a numeric variable and increment it in a GF formula using the same conditional logic.  Then, display the resulting total in a formula below the "action".

You didn't describe what level of aggregation you are after (grand total across level 1 subtotals? Level 1 total across level-2 subtotals?) so it's difficult to refer to appropriate level of "action" in more concrete terms.